# Hide or change the "no data in local tile cache" message in GMap.NET

Tags: c#, wpf, gmap.net

I'm using GMap.NET. When zooming too much on the map and no image is available for the zone, a exception square prints on the map. This is OK, I don't want to change the behavior. I just want to make up the GmapControl, and I'm almost done. All I need now is changing or removing the exception message :  "Exception : no data in local tile cache". But I can't find the right property...

For people interested in, I've asked on the GMAP official topic, and I had some interesting answers, except for this one part : http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/389159

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/389159, I embarked on a similar mission:

```
mapControl.EmptytileBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Gainsboro);
mapControl.EmptyTileText = String.Empty;
mapControl.EmptyTileBorders = new Pen(Color.Gray);
```

However, GMap exposes no property to hide the exception text, and after removing the offending DrawString inside (GMAP v1.6, line 753 of GMapControl.cs), I recompiled and found that the binaries were not the same as the source!

The recompiled source, now does not display the exception text at all (when using cached mode only).

As a result - all that was necessary in my case was a rebuild or Core and WinForms.
When zooming in, GMAP now uses previous map data as far as possible, then eventually draws a blank white tile by default when the zoom is about 10 levels lower than the previously available level.

This behavior is acceptable - after all, who except for a debugger/developer would want to see bright exception text instead of a blank image? :)